# How to cross compile TensorFlowr1.15 c++ static library in ubuntu for arm64

Tags: c++, tensorflow, static, cross-compiling, arm64

Now, I get the  TensorFlowr1.15 c++ static library `libtensorflow-core.a` through run `../tensorflow-r1.15/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_linux.sh` in ubuntu22.

But, I need to use it in arm64.

**How to cross compile TensorFlowr1.15 c++ static library in ubuntu for arm64?**

I have no idea for this.Can anyone give me some solutions?
Thank you very much!

Comment: For starters, have you found a cross-compiler for the target platform? Did you study the [documentation for tensorflow lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm) as it is probably a similar process?

Comment: I try [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_cmake_arm?hl=zh-cn).

I use `gcc-arm-8.3-2019.03-x86_64-aarch64-linux-gnu` 

and run `cmake -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}gcc   -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=${ARMCC_PREFIX}g++   -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}"   -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="${ARMCC_FLAGS}"   -DCMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON   -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME=Linux   -DCMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR=aarch64   ../tensorflow1.x/tensorflow-r1.15/tensorflow/`

But it shows `CMake Error: The source directory "/home/wmc/tensorflow1.x/tensorflow-r1.15/tensorflow" does not appear to contain CMakeLists.txt.`

Comment: Clarifying information should go into the question. And did you check the obvious? How is tensor flow compiled normally?

Comment: Thank u for your reply! I run the `../tensorflow-r1.15/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/build_all_linux.sh` command to get static library `libtensorflow-core.a`. `readelf -h libtensorflow-core.a` log follows: `Machine: Advanced Micro Devices X86-64` .Obviously, it is in x86 through this way. But, I need c++ static library for arm. I have no idea to construct this library. As far as I know, tensorflow lite and TensorFlow cross-compile their static libraries differently. Do you know TensorFlowr c static library compilation or cross-compilation for arm? Could you help me? Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is actually a secondary build system. The primary build system is Bazel, which [supports cross compilation natively](https://bazel.build/extending/platforms)

Comment: OK, thank you very much!

Have you try to cross compile TensorFlowr c++ static library in ubuntu for arm64?

If you have, could you give some directions？

How does Bazel cross-compile, I still don't understand it very well, I will learn it.

Answer (score 0):

**I run the same way on arrch64 server**.
run `build_all_linux.sh -a arm64`, I also get TensorFlowr1.15 c++ static library `libtensorflow-core.a`. **This lib is for arm64**.
I solve this question.

Now, I try to build tensorflow-on-arm, but it doesn't success.